# Why is my PCI-Express 3.0 graphics card running as PCI-Express x16 v2.0?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

My new computer is a top **value machine**:

```
Motherboard ASUS CrossHair V Formula Z
CPU FX-9370
DRAM 2.133MHz
GPU Radeon R9 280X
PSU Corsair AX1200i
```

All **drivers are up to date** (as for today: September 2014), both Motherboard and GPU **BIOS are to its latest** version too.

But [TechPowerUp GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) yields (translated from my spanish version):

> "The graphics card reports PCI-Express x16 v3.0 capable, but it is
>   working at PCI-Express x16 v2.0"

Why is not my graphics card at its maximum, and what can I do to solve this?

(Please request any other data if needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/CROSSHAIR_V_FORMULAZ/ :

> AMD® 990FX Chipset is designed to support up to 5.2GT/s
>   HyperTransport™ 3.0 (HT 3.0) interface speed and **dual PCI Express™ 2.0**
>   **x16 graphics.** It is optimized with AMD® latest AM3+ and multi-core
>   CPUs to provide excellent system performance and overclocking
>   capabilities.

Your board only goes up to PCI-E 2.0.

Comment: Well... there goes the best board for AM3+ that I could find in the shop. The answer was too obvious. Thanks you, @ultrasawblade.